# Null pointer exception using Time Pickers

Tags: java, android, dialog, nullpointerexception, timepicker

I'm trying to make a simple app that opens the time picker dialog when you click the "Check" button, and once you set the time and tap "OK", it checks the system time and outputs whether it is correct.  However, I am given a null pointer exception on line 21 of MainActivity.java.  At the moment the code is simply set up to bring up the dialog once "Check" is tapped.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.timechecker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
    return null;
}
public void checkTime(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}

}
```

TimePickerFragment.java

```
package com.example.timechecker;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.timechecker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.timechecker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.timechecker.TimePickerFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/whatTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What time is it?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="checkTime"
    android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: indicate the line in your code please, as you kinda didnt even mention the class in which the nullpointer occurs

Comment: Mentioned that it's in MainActivity.java

Comment: sorry, must have missed it :)
so its exactly the line i guessed. Check my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah i see what is happening here.

```
public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
    return null;
}
public void checkTime(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}
```

You are overriding getSupportFragmentManager to return null, and after that you call the method to show the dialog, looks like you created the nullpointer on purpose? =D

Comment: It would seem that is so haha, though, I'm not quite sure what I should return?

Comment: use getFragmentManager(), Activity doesnt support getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Change your activity to be a FragmentActivity. Delete your implementation of getSupportFragmentManager(). Done.

Comment: That worked, @dymmeh, thanks! Also thanks for the help, DanielBo.